# Getting the wrong date from cell using PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, date, unix, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel and trying to get the date values from the cells, but for some reason they give me the **wrong date**.

```
$dt_column  = $obj_sheet->getCell('A1');
$unix_date  = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($dt_column);
$date       = gmdate('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $unix_date);
```

The file is in .xlsx format. The value of the cell, in LibreOffice Calc, is displayed as 1/7/2017, (01/07/2017 on the formula input, don't know if there's any practical difference in handling it on PHPExcel dates).

The **returned value** given to `$dt_column` is 42917.

The **value attributed** to `$unix`_date is -2208988800.

The **value attributed** to `$date` is 2036-02-07 00:00:00.

I tried to manually convert the Excel date values to Unix date values using the formula `UNIX_DATE = (EXCEL_DATE - 25569) * 86400`, as u'd imagine, same result.

`PHPExcel_Shared_Date::$_excelBaseDate` is set to `CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900`.

**How can I get the correct date?**

**Answered**

Comment: `$obj_sheet->getCell('A1');`

returns the Cell object at `A1`, which contains a lot of information about the cell including formatting and style.

If you want the value from a cell, then you need to use

    `$obj_sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();`

Comment: Ops, thank you. I was trying to get this to work for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Excel calculates a date as the addition / substraction of x since 1/1/1900.
So your date is 42917 days past 1/1/1900. You can best use that to calculate the correct date.

Example:

```
$d = strtotime("1900-1-1 + ".$dt_column." days");
```

$d will be the timestamp in UNIX format which can be used with the date() function to format.

Good luck!